# How to delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame and I want to delete rows from it where the length of the string in a particular column is greater than 2.

I expect to be able to do this (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881165/slice-pandas-dataframe-by-row)):

```
df[(len(df['column name']) < 2)]
```

but I just get the error:

```
KeyError: u'no item named False'
```

What am I doing wrong?

(Note: I know I can use `df.dropna()` to get rid of rows that contain any `NaN`, but I didn't see how to remove rows based on a conditional expression.)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

When you do `len(df['column name'])` you are just getting one number, namely the number of rows in the DataFrame (i.e., the length of the column itself).  If you want to apply `len` to each element in the column, use `df['column name'].map(len)`.  So try

```
df[df['column name'].map(len) < 2]
```

Comment: I came up with a way using a list comprehension: `df[[(len(x) < 2) for x in df['column name']]]` but yours is much nicer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: In case someone needs a more complex comparion, a lambda can always be used.
    `df[df['column name'].map(lambda x: str(x)!=".")]`

Comment: For some reason, none of the other options have worked for me, except the one posted by @4lberto . I'm on `pandas 0.23.4` and python 3.6

Comment: I would add a `.copy()` at the end, in case you want to later edit this dataframe (for example, assigning new columns would raise the "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" warning.

Answer (score 1537):

To directly answer this question's original title "How to delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression" (which I understand is not necessarily the OP's problem but could help other users coming across this question) one way to do this is to use the [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method:

```
df = df.drop(some labels)
df = df.drop(df[<some boolean condition>].index)
```

**Example**

To remove all rows where column 'score' is < 50:

```
df = df.drop(df[df.score < 50].index)
```

In place version (as pointed out in comments)

```
df.drop(df[df.score < 50].index, inplace=True)
```

**Multiple conditions**

(see [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing))

> The operators are: `|` for `or`, `&` for `and`, and `~` for `not`. These must be
> grouped by using parentheses.

To remove all rows where column 'score' is < 50 and > 20

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.score < 50) & (df.score > 20)].index)
```

Comment: I just want to remark, that the drop function supports inplace replacement. I.e,. your solution is the same as df.drop(df[df.score < 50].index, inplace=True). Nevertheless didn't know the "index" trick. Helped me a lot

Comment: Just want to point out that before you use this index trick you need to be sure that your index values are unique (or call `reset_index()`).  I found this out the hard way when way to many rows got dropped from my dataframe.

Comment: how do I drop all rows where the column type is str? I want to only keep list column types. I have tried

`test = df.drop(df[df['col1'].dtype == str].index)`
but I get the error `KeyError: False`

I have also tried `df.drop(df[df.col1.dtype == str].index)` and `df.drop(df[type(df.cleaned_norm_email) == str].index)` but nothing seems to work? Can anyone advise. Thanks! @User

Comment: This is an old question but... @aquatically-challenged-fish is a lot faster than this one. Note that you compute `df[(df.score < 50) & (df.score > 20)]` as part of your answer. If you reversed this to do `df = df[(df.score >= 50) | (df.score <= 20)]` you would get your answer much faster.

Comment: @Jay - Lets say you have a column with non unique data and wants to use that column as an index.  Lets say I apply reset_index().  What happens to these rows with duplicated column data?

Comment: @RoobieNuby - they are not same condition.

Comment: @Nguaial No they are not the same. They are opposite. So instead of dropping, as suggested above, I suggest keeping, as in `df = df[...` rather than `df = df.drop(...`

Comment: I added a time comparison to `drop` to the `df = df[...` answer. I agree it should be accepted instead given the speed.

Comment: @RoobieNuby they are not the same conditions, clarification follows:  set1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8); set2 = (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), set1 < 5 & set2 > 4 = (4, 5) whereas set1 >= 5 | set2 <=4 = (3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: What exactly does '.index'?

Comment: @Guerra the .index will get you a list of the dataframe's index values. In this case, useful as a parameter to the drop function,  so it deletes those specific "rows"

Comment: `reset_index(inplace=True)` fixed my issue of rows being deleted for no reason. Thanks, @Jay!

Comment: Can I always reference a column by its name in the ```df.columnname``` format?

Comment: In my case, I wanted to remove lines from a dataframe based on values from a given column, only if those values happen to be in a certain range (e.g. from 30 to 40) , so I used  ``df.drop(df[df['column-name'].between(30, 40)].index, inplace=True)``

Comment: What is there is two index values which are same , it removes both regardless of one is true and one is false

Answer (score 190):

You can assign the `DataFrame` to a filtered version of itself:

```
df = df[df.score > 50]
```

This is faster than `drop`:

```
%%timeit
test = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randn(int(1e6))})
test = test[test.x < 0]
# 54.5 ms ± 2.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
test = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randn(int(1e6))})
test.drop(test[test.x > 0].index, inplace=True)
# 201 ms ± 17.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
test = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.randn(int(1e6))})
test = test.drop(test[test.x > 0].index)
# 194 ms ± 7.03 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: How do I check for multiple column using or condition?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611065/efficient-way-to-apply-multiple-filters-to-pandas-dataframe-or-series

Comment: Be careful, if there still is a reference to the original unfiltered dataframe around then the filtered version is a view into (also known as slice of) the original dataframe, which will cause trouble if the filtered dataframe later needs to be modified (such as getting a column added, for example). In this case one might want to make an explicit copy, as in df=df[mask].copy(). Here is a code example showing the issue by rasing a warning: df = pd.DataFrame([(1,0),(2,3)]);
df1 = df;
df = df[df[0]>1];
df['b'] = 'some value';

Answer (score 23):

I will expand on @User's generic solution to provide a `drop` free alternative. This is for folks directed here based on the question's title (not OP 's problem)

Say you want to delete all rows with negative values. One liner solution is:-

```
df = df[(df > 0).all(axis=1)]
```

**Step by step Explanation:--**

**Let's generate a 5x5 random normal distribution data frame**

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,5), columns=list('ABCDE'))
      A         B         C         D         E
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558
1 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357 -0.103219  0.410599
2  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
3  0.333674  1.494079 -0.205158  0.313068 -0.854096
4 -2.552990  0.653619  0.864436 -0.742165  2.269755
```

**Let the condition be deleting negatives. A boolean df satisfying the condition:-**

```
df > 0
      A     B      C      D      E
0   True  True   True   True   True
1  False  True  False  False   True
2   True  True   True   True   True
3   True  True  False   True  False
4  False  True   True  False   True
```

**A boolean series for all rows satisfying the condition**  Note if any element in the row fails the condition the row is marked false

```
(df > 0).all(axis=1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```

**Finally filter out rows from data frame based on the condition**

```
df[(df > 0).all(axis=1)]
      A         B         C         D         E
0  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893  1.867558
2  0.144044  1.454274  0.761038  0.121675  0.443863
```

You can assign it back to df to actually *delete* vs *filter* ing done above
`df = df[(df > 0).all(axis=1)]`

This can easily be extended to filter out rows containing NaN s (non numeric entries):-
`df = df[(~df.isnull()).all(axis=1)]`

This can also be simplified for cases like: Delete all rows where column E is negative

```
df = df[(df.E>0)]
```

I would like to end with some profiling stats on why @User's `drop` solution is slower than raw column based filtration:-

```
%timeit df_new = df[(df.E>0)]
345 µs ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit dft.drop(dft[dft.E < 0].index, inplace=True)
890 µs ± 94.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

A column is basically a `Series` i.e a `NumPy` array, it can be indexed without any cost. For folks interested in how the underlying memory organization plays into execution speed here is a great [Link on Speeding up Pandas](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/732/ggbaker/content/pandas-speed.html):

Answer (score 13):

In pandas you can do `str.len` with your boundary and using the Boolean result to filter it .

```
df[df['column name'].str.len().lt(2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to drop rows of data frame on the basis of some complicated condition on the column value then writing that in the way shown above can be complicated. I have the following simpler solution which always works. Let us assume that you want to drop the column with 'header' so get that column in a list first.

```py
text_data = df['name'].tolist()
```

now apply some function on the every element of the list and put that in a panda series:

```py
text_length = pd.Series([func(t) for t in text_data])
```

in my case I was just trying to get the number of tokens:

```py
text_length = pd.Series([len(t.split()) for t in text_data])
```

now add one extra column with the above series in the data frame:

```py
df = df.assign(text_length = text_length .values)
```

now we can apply condition on the new column such as:

```py
df = df[df.text_length  >  10]
```

```py
def pass_filter(df, label, length, pass_type):

    text_data = df[label].tolist()

    text_length = pd.Series([len(t.split()) for t in text_data])

    df = df.assign(text_length = text_length .values)

    if pass_type == 'high':
        df = df[df.text_length  >  length]

    if pass_type == 'low':
        df = df[df.text_length  <  length]

    df = df.drop(columns=['text_length'])

    return df
```