# DataFrame.drop not dropping expected rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that includes rows that I want to drop based on values in a column "population":

```
data['population'].value_counts()

general population                          21
developmental delay                         20
sibling                                      2
general population + developmental delay     1
dtype: int64
```

here, I want to drop the two rows that have `sibling` as the value. So, I believe the following should do the trick:

```
data = data.drop(data.population=='sibling', axis=0)
```

It does drop 2 rows, as you can see in the resulting value counts, but they were *not* the rows with the specified value.

```
data.population.value_counts()

developmental delay                         20
general population                          19
sibling                                      2
general population + developmental delay     1
dtype: int64
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: use `data = data[data.population != 'sibling']`

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851

Answer (score 7):

[`dataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) accepts an index (list of labels) as a parameter, not a mask.
To use `drop` you should do:

```
data = data.drop(data.index[data.population == 'sibling'])
```

however it is much simpler to do

```
data = data[data.population != 'sibling']
```

Comment: You can do a similar thing with a condition over multiple columns: `data = data[(data[['col1','col2','col3']] != 0).all(axis=1)]` - to drop all rows with zeros in at least one of those columns.

Comment: caution: method 1 will not re-index the data!