# excluding rows from a pandas dataframe based on column value and not index value

Tags: python, pandas

I looked at the unique values in a column of a dataframe - pandas that I have. And there are some names in one of the columns that I do not want to include, how do I remove those rows from the dataframe, without using index value notation, but by saying if row value = "this" then remove

like...

```
new = df.copy

df['some column'].drop_values('this','that','other')
```

Answer (score 44):

See [**indexing with `isin`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin) (also, [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)):

```
mask = df['some column'].isin(['this', 'that', 'other'])
df[~mask]
```

Comment: Thanks @Behzad! does the [~idx] notation, mean show everything in the dataframe which are not in variable, idx?

Is this also another way to do it?
df[df.line_race != 0]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value

Comment: @yoshiserry see [Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: @yoshiserry also see [indexing with isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin)