# Selecting Unique Rows between Two DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames A and B of unequal dimensions. I would like to create a data frame C such that it ONLY contains rows that are unique between A and B. I tried to follow this solution ([excluding rows from a pandas dataframe based on column value and not index value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392786/excluding-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-column-value-and-not-index-value?rq=1)) but could not get it to work.

Here's example:

Assume this to be DF_A:

```
    Star_ID         Loc_ID      pmRA        pmDE    Field     Jmag    Hmag  
 2M00000032+5737103  4264    0.000000    0.000000    N7789   10.905  10.635
 2M00000068+5710233  4264    8.000000    -18.000000  N7789   10.664  10.132
 2M00000222+5625359  4264    0.000000    0.000000    N7789   11.982  11.433
 2M00000818+5634264  4264    0.000000    0.000000    N7789   12.501  11.892
 2M00001242+5524391  4264    0.000000    -4.000000   N7789   12.091  11.482
```

And this to be DF_B:

```
2M00000032+5737103  
2M00000068+5710233
2M00001242+5524391
```

So, the first two and last Star_ID are common between DF_A and DF_B. I would like to create DF_C such that:

DF_C:

```
        Star_ID         Loc_ID      pmRA        pmDE    Field     Jmag    Hmag
     2M00000222+5625359  4264    0.000000    0.000000    N7789   11.982  11.433
     2M00000818+5634264  4264    0.000000    0.000000    N7789   12.501  11.892
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
In [7]:

df1[~df1.Star_ID.isin(df2.Star_ID)]

Out[7]:

              Star_ID  Loc_ID  pmRA  pmDE  Field    Jmag    Hmag
2  2M00000222+5625359    4264     0     0  N7789  11.982  11.433
3  2M00000818+5634264    4264     0     0  N7789  12.501  11.892

[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

So what we do here is we create a boolean mask, we ask for where `Star_ID` values is in both dataframes, however by using the `~` we `NOT` the condition which in effect negates it. The one you linked to is pretty much the same thing but I think you maybe didn't understand the syntax?

**EDIT**

In order to get both values that are only in df1 and values that are only in df2 you could do this

```
unique_vals = df1[~df1.Star_ID.isin(df2.Star_ID)].append(df2[~df2.Star_ID.isin(df1.Star_ID)], ignore_index=True)
```

**Further edit**

So the problem was that the csv had leading spaces, this caused all values to be unique in both datasets, to correct this you need to do this:

```
df1.Apogee_ID = df1.Apogee_ID.str.lstrip()
```

Comment: Well, I tried the linked example this way: 
idx = df_mds['2MASS_ID'].isin(df_survey['Apogee_ID'])
df_new = df_survey[~idx]. This gave me the following error: "Unalignable boolean Series key provided". Perhaps, the names have to be the same in two dataframes?

Comment: Have you tried my method above, assuming your column data is correct then what you wrote probably should've worked, can you post your problematic data if the above does not work

Comment: How you actually format the comment? My above comment not in the format I like it to be in.

Comment: No, I am about to try. Will let you know in few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: Which comment? you mean like `this`? you just put ` accents around the text (grave accents I think they are called)

Comment: I don't think this is quite right; it doesn't capture ids in df2 not in df1?

Comment: @exp1orer yes that is true but it does work on the example data, I'll update my answer to satisfay that condition

Comment: yeah, it does not work on my data. I will send you my files as dropbox link. Thanks! Oh, will try the edit first.

Comment: No, it does not work. I JUST want stars that are NOT common between the two lists. Here are the two lists I'm working on (https://db.tt/qoC51XES). Note that DF_A = 'List_A' and DF_B = 'MDWARF_CURRENT_LIST.txt'. I expect the unique number of stars to be about 95. Your example either gives me 348 or 608 stars. Thank you SO MUCH for working this out for me!

Comment: Well the first problem I can see is that you have leading spaces in your ListA.csv for `Apogee_ID`, is that your problem?

Comment: No, this is the command I have used: "unique_vals = df_Mdwarfs[~df_Mdwarfs.Apogee_ID.isin(df_mds.Apogee_ID)]"

Comment: where df_Mdwarfs is DF_A and DF_B = df_mds

Comment: OK I get for Mdwarfs 255 total, of which 186 are present in the other df, 69 are not for mds dataframe I get 348 total, of which 186 are present in Mdwarfs, leaving 162 not present, so I would expect the total of unique vals from both dfs to be 162 + 69 = 231. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51983/discussion-between-aging-gorrila-and-edchum)

Comment: Great answer... Exactly what I have searched for 