# Create column o difference between two pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have **firstDF:**

```
rs     Chr      MapInfo         Name       SourceSeq
1       A1       B1              C1          D1
2       A2       B2              C2          D2
3       A3       B3              C3          D3
4       A4       B4              C4          D4
5       A5       B5              C5          D5
```

And **secondDF:**

```
Chr       MapInfo     Name    SourceSeq       Unnamed: 0       rs
 1          A1          B1        C1             D1            E1
 4          A4          B4        C4             D4            E4
 8          A8          B8        C8             D8            E8
 10         A10         B10       C10            D10           E10
```

I need to create a new data frame contains only rows from *secondDF* which does not exist in first:

**newDF:**

```
Chr       MapInfo     Name    SourceSeq       Unnamed: 0       rs
8          A8          B8        C8             D8            E8
10         A10         B10       C10            D10           E10
```

I want filter it by `Name`. What will be better way to do that?

I trough about a `fullouter` merge but the cols are different and honestly I don't know how to do it proper.

Second, think was a loop but it's not efficient.

And last I tried do ith by:

```
new= secondDF[~firstDF.Name.isin(secondDF.name)]
```

but i got:

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match

Can someone give me advice about that task?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460345/selecting-unique-rows-between-two-dataframes-in-pandas

Comment: "*index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match*" , try resetting the index

Comment: you can get help regarding this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28902170/11548219)

Comment: In your sample need `new= firstDF[~firstDF.Name.isin(secondDF.name)]`, also columns values not matched between both DataFrames? Like need match `SourceSeq from first with Unnamed: 0 from second` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is change mask - compare `secondDF.Name` by column from `firstDF`, from sample data it is `MapInfo` column, in real data seems `Name` column for boolean mask with same size and index values like `secondDF`, because is filtered `secondDF` DataFrame:

```
new= secondDF[~secondDF.Name.isin(firstDF.MapInfo)] 
print (new)
   Chr MapInfo Name SourceSeq Unnamed: 0   rs
2    8      A8   B8        C8         D8   E8
3   10     A10  B10       C10        D10  E10
```