# How to Drop All The Rows Based on Multiple Values Found in the "Fruit "Column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this simple dataframe

```
Num   Fruit   Price
1     Apple   1.00
1     Apple   1.00
2     Apple   1.50
2     Orange  1.50
3     Orange  1.00
3     Banana  0.50
```

I want to drop all the rows which have the fruit `Apple` or `Orange`

The expected output should be like this:

```
Num  Fruit   Price
3    Banana  0.50
```

I tried to doing the following syntax, but somehow it did not drop all the rows in the dataframe

```
>>> df.drop(df.Fruit.isin(["Apple","Orange"]))
Fruit Num Price
2   Apple   2  1.50
3  Orange   2  1.50
4  Orange   3  1.00
5  Banana   3  0.50
```

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to pass the indices of the rows to be dropped, but you are passing a boolean array. You can change it to:

```
df.drop(df[df.Fruit.isin(["Apple", "Orange"])].index)
Out: 
   Num   Fruit  Price
5    3  Banana    0.5
```

Or you can select the rows that don't contain apple or orange:

```
df[~(df.Fruit.isin(["Apple", "Orange"]))]
Out: 
   Num   Fruit  Price
5    3  Banana    0.5
```

Comment: Note that you should pass the argument `inplace=True` to `drop` in order to mutate the dataframe rather than returning a view with the rows dropped.