# Removing DataFrame rows in Pandas based on column type

Tags: pandas, python-2.x

I have a Panda's DataFrame and in an specific column, there are some values of different type than the desired one. I've tried to use a similar approach like the one exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value), but it doesn't work. In my case some rows store `floats` and others store `strings`, I want to keep only the `strings`.

This is what I tried.

import pandas as pd

```
d = {"name": [1.0, 2.0, "hello", "world"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print df
print df[(type(df["name"]) == type("str"))]
```

Obviously, I got an error related to a `KeyError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `.str` accessor with `isalpha`
this returns `NaN` for floats so I `fillna(False)`

```
df[df.name.str.isalpha().fillna(False)]
```

[image]