# stripping data from two XLXS cells to csv

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

im having an issue where im trying to take data from two cells in an excel spread sheet and put them into a csv file. the data is lat and lon coordinates so they have to be side by side to be read by the program.  here is what i have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import xlwt
import xlrd
import csv
import os, openpyxl, glob
from openpyxl import Workbook


with open ('test.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
  spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')

  for file in glob.glob ("/test"):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test-data.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    def lat():
      for row in ws.iter_rows('Q2:Q65536'):
        for cell in row:
          lat = cell.value
          return lat
    def lon():
      for row in ws.iter_rows('R2:R65536'):
        for cell in row:
          lon = cell.value
          return lon  

  cord=lat()+","+lon()
  print (lat()+","+lon()) #just to see if its working
  #spamwriter.writerow([cord]) uncomment to write to file
```

however it only gives me the first row of data not the rest of the rows (test-data has around 1500 rows). how would i make it to finish going through the file?

Comment: Not sure what this have to do with the tag Excel as it's a CSV you are reading. I have no knowledge of python, but shouldn't the FOR have a NEXT or something that encloses the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the most dynamic way, but I would use pandas for this task.  It has built in `pd.read_excel()` and `pd.to_csv()` functions.

```
import pandas as pd
import string

latColumn = string.lowercase.index('q') # determine index that corresponds to Excel Column letter (user lower case)
longColumn = string.lowercase.index('r') # Does not work for AA, BB, ...

data = pd.read_excel('test-data.xlsx', 'Sheet1', parse_cols=[latColumn,longColumn])

# Total number of rows being read in 65536 - 2 = 65534

csvOut = "foo.csv"
data[:65534].to_csv(csvOut, index=False, header=False)
```

If you need append to the file and not replace it, change the  `data[:65534].to_csv(....)` to

```
open(csvOut, 'a') as f:  #append to the .csv file of your likings
     data[:65534].to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: you are a life saver!!! thanks so much! is there a way to catch bad data? for some reason some cells have "None" in them and i need to either replace it as 0 or remove it.

Comment: @stcoyle,  If you're looking to replace all the "None" values with 0 then you can insert data = data.replace(to_replace="None", value=0)`  if you want to remove the row with that column then you can use `data = data[data.Lat != "None"]` and `data = data[data.Long != "None"]`

Comment: In my test.xlsx dataset I have my latitude and longitude as "Lat" and "Long". You will have to set them to whatever yours are named.   Check out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Comment: you are a godsend! wish i asked this question last week haha thanks sooooo much!