# Remove rows from pandas DataFrame based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am a newbie to pandas so please forgive the newbie question!

I have the following code;

```
import pandas as pd

pet_names = ["Name","Species"
"Jack","Cat"
"Jill","Dog"
"Tom","Cat"
"Harry","Dog"
"Hannah","Dog"]

df = pd.DataFrame(pet_names)

df = df[df['Species']!='Cat']

print(df)
```

I would like to remove all the rows that contain "Cat" in the "Species" column, leaving all the dogs behind. How do I do this? Unfortunately, this code is currently returning errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

#### General *`boolean indexing`*

```
df[df['Species'] != 'Cat']
# df[df['Species'].ne('Cat')]

  Index    Name Species
1     1    Jill     Dog
3     3   Harry     Dog
4     4  Hannah     Dog
```

---

#### `df.query`

```
df.query("Species != 'Cat'")

  Index    Name Species
1     1    Jill     Dog
3     3   Harry     Dog
4     4  Hannah     Dog
```

For information on the `pd.eval()` family of functions, their features and use cases, please visit [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval).

---

#### `df.isin`

```
df[~df['Species'].isin(['Cat'])]

  Index    Name Species
1     1    Jill     Dog
3     3   Harry     Dog
4     4  Hannah     Dog
```

Comment: I just upvoted you four times for each answer.  Too bad, SO didn't recognize those clicks.

Comment: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Species'" - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JamesGeddes If you are using the same data, as in your post, that's why. You have issues with your input data. Try this: `pet_names = [["Jack","Cat"], ["Jill","Dog"], ["Tom","Cat"], ["Harry","Dog"] ,["Hannah","Dog"] ];
df = pd.DataFrame(pet_names,columns =["Name","Species"])` (from Bharath's post)

Comment: @ScottBoston hahaha if only!

Comment: Multiple choices +1

Comment: now you have my upvote ~Also recommend `df.query`, especially for multiple index

Answer (score 1):

Your code `df[df['Species']!='Cat']` is correct. It's your dataframe initialization code that is wrong. See the other comment by user `cs95`.

While the other answer is correct, I prefer to use `drop()` when deleting rows because it is more straightforward than using inverse logic (keeping rows that are not Cats). There's no difference for a simple example like this, but if you starting having more complex logic for which rows to drop, then it matters. For example, delete rows where `A=1 AND (B=2 OR C=3)`.

Here's how you use `drop()` with conditional logic:

```
df.drop( df.query(" `Species`=='Cat' ").index)
```

This is a more scalable syntax for more complicated logic.