# Pandas GroupBy and Mean over Date Range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I would like to compute the mean per ID using `groupby` and `mean`. However, I only need the rows where `Date` is between year `2016-01-01` and `2017-12-31`.

```
d = {'ID': ['STCK123', 'STCK123', 'STCK123'], 'Amount': [250, 400, 350], 
     'Date': ['2016-01-20', '2017-09-25', '2018-05-15']}



data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data = data[['ID', 'Amount', 'Date']]

data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

This gives following df:

```
    ID  Amount    Date
STCK123 250 2016-01-20
STCK123 400 2017-09-25
STCK123 350 2018-05-15
```

When I use:

`data.groupby(['ID'])['Amount'].agg('mean')`

It takes all rows into account, resulting in a mean value of `333.3`. How can I exclude the rows where `Date` is 2018 (yielding a mean value of `(250+400)/2=325`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a pre-filtering step with `query`:

```
df.query('Date.dt.year != 2018').groupby('ID').mean()

         Amount
ID             
STCK123     325
```

More uses for `eval`, `query`, and associated parameters can be found here in my writeup: [Dynamic Expression Evaluation in pandas using pd.eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779986/dynamic-expression-evaluation-in-pandas-using-pd-eval)

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45489976/4909087) for more methods on *dropping* rows before calling `groupby`.

---

You can also `mask` those rows, without having to drop them. NaNs are excluded from the `GroupBy` aggregation.

```
df.mask(df.Date.dt.year == 2018).groupby('ID').mean()

         Amount
ID             
STCK123   325.0
```