# Can't pass iterable into pandas df to drop a row with a specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a bunch of csvs into a database and would like to get rid of any rows from these tables that have the value "-". I'm trying to do the same thing in the folllowing link but using an iterable instead of predetermined column as I don't know which tables and columns will have these values:

[Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

My code:
dfs = {}

```
for doc in fList:
    i = "{}\\{}".format(path, doc)

    df = pd.read_csv(i)

    for col in df.columns:
        df = df[df.col != "-"]
```

This returns the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-291-43edac7a4ed7> in <module>()
      8     #print dfs
      9     for col in df:
---> 10         df = df[df.col != "-"]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2968             if name in self._info_axis:
   2969                 return self[name]
-> 2970             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2971 
   2972     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'col'
```

It seems that I cannot use the iterable in the loop. It would defeat the perpose of writing the script if I have to open each file and change the values. Is there anyway to loop through the tables and delete rows with the bad values?

Comment: what happens when you try `df = df.loc[df[col] != '-']?`

Comment: @MattR same TypeError: invalid type expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot dynamically access `df`'s column using a variable as you are trying, that leads to an `AttributeError`. Because the `.` will search for `df's` attribute `col`, and not `df`'s attribute `<value in col>`. There's a difference.

If you wanted to, you'd need the `__getitem__` accessor; `df[col]`. However, you should avoid loopy solutions where you can. Here are a couple of alternatives.

**Option 1**
For your case, `eq` + `any` should suffice.

```
df = df[df.astype(str).eq('-').any(1)]                # `astype` conversion
```

Or,

```
df = df[df.select_dtypes(['object']).eq('-').any(1)]  # `select_dtypes`, thanks MaxU!
```

---

**Option 2**
Another option would be to use a `na_values` argument with `read_csv`, so when reading in your data, these values are converted to NaN, which you can drop.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values=['-'])
```

And now, call `dropna` on your data -

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED tried your solution and got this: TypeError: Could not compare ['-'] with block values

Comment: @ShaunO `df[df.astype(str).eq('-').any(1)]` it seems like you don't have all string columns.

Comment: @COLDSPEED that did it! Weird, I was sure they all were strings. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ShaunO No problem, feel free to vote on, and accept the answer if it was helpful. I'd appreciate it ;-)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Done!

Comment: a little improvement: `df = df[df.select_dtypes(['object']).eq('-').any(1)]`

Comment: @COLDSPEED Sorry. I'm actually getting some strange results with this. I want to delete rows with "-" in an effort to clean data. All the columns need to be numeric to perform stats on them and the "-" (census data for Nan) is throwing it all off. When I run the .eq solution it changed one entire column "-" and then randomly changed other column values in another table to "-".

Comment: @ShaunO Wow, you should've said so. In that case, When calling `read_csv`, add a `na_values=['-']` argument, so those values are made null. Then, just call `dropna`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes, a thousand apologies