# How to avoid a string containing a certain word during a count through Pandas

Tags: pandas, count, sum

Having created a dataframe:

```
df_lev = df[["column_name"]]
```

now, I'm counting each single unique content of this column with:

```
df_lev["column_name"].drop_duplicates().count().sum()
```

Question:
Since there is a string (containing a specific word to avoid) that I need to jump during this count,

1. Is there a way to jump it?
2. how can avoid that string during the counting?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can make your original query simpler.

In pandas there is a command `nunique` which will count the number of unique items in the column as follows:

```
df_lev["column_name"].nunique()
```

Or

```
df_lev.column_name.nunique()
```

Using the following dataframe (df):

```
df_lev = pd.DataFrame({'column_name':['String I want','String I dont want', 'String I want', 'String I want 2', 'String I dont want']})
```

Which:

```
print(df_lev)
          column_name
0       String I want
1  String I dont want
2       String I want
3     String I want 2
4  String I dont want
```

By eye, we can see that there are 3 unique string values in `column_name`. We can also use `nunique` as mentioned before:

```
print(df_lev.column_name.nunique())
3
```

If there is a string you don't want to include in this count, in this case `'String I dont want'` we can create a new df which excludes this string (read this thread for more: [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value))

```
df_lev_new = df_lev[df_lev.column_name != 'String I dont want']
```

This will remove the unwanted string, leaving our new df with only 2 unique string values :

```
print(df_lev_new)
       column_name
0    String I want
2    String I want
3  String I want 2
```

Which we can count using `nunique` as before:

```
print(df_lev_new.column_name.nunique())
2
```

I've used python 3.x for this. If you're using python 2.x, you need to remove all `print(x)` and replace with `print x`