# dropping rows from dataframe having values in range

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame, where one of the column is `days.to.play`. Now I want to drop any rows, where it is more than 1000. The name of the data frame is `basketball_football_2`.

I tried couple of solutions such as:

```
basketball_football_2.loc[~(basketball_football_2['days.to.play'] > 1000)]
```

OR

```
basketball_football_2['day.to.play'] = basketball_football_2[basketball_football_2['day.to.play'] >= 1000]
```

OR

```
basketball_football_2.drop(basketball_football_2.loc[basketball_football_2['days.to.play']>=1000].index, inplace=True)
```

but it is dropping all the values and making the entire data frame empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18173074/4100253

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already provided by @Marek Here's the link which should help you: [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value/18173074#18173074)

Here's the code just for the easy reference purpose:

```
basketball_football_2 = basketball_football_2[basketball_football_2['days.to.play'].values < 1000]
```

Note: It's really a bad practice to use "**.**" in your column names. Instead use something like "**_**".

Good Luck!

May the *CODE* be with you!

Comment: This is working fine @Me-So-Cool. I am new to ML, so please excuse silly questions. Going by the same logic, if I do something like:     basketball_football_1 = basketball_football_1[basketball_football_1['days.to.play'].values > 500 & basketball_football_1['days.to.play'].values < 1000] to select values between 500 and 1000, why I am getting error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()".