# how to delete row by value of specific coulmn?

Tags: python

i have made this code script and im trying to delete the sepcific row where 'username' column in my csv file , while the adding loop is running
my excel file looks like this

im tried to do it and lost all the way , thank for your help guys

i wonder to delete the row after the adding has done i added line 
where i added 
HERE I NEED TO INSERT THE DELETE METHOD

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerEmpty, InputPeerChannel, InputPeerUser
from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import PeerFloodError, UserPrivacyRestrictedError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import InviteToChannelRequest


import sys
import csv
import traceback
import time

api_id = 123456
api_hash = '############################'
phone = '+11111111111'
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))


users = []
with open("filepath/members.csv", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    next(rows, None)
    for row in rows:
        user = {}
        user['username'] = row[0]
        user['id'] = int(row[1])
        user['access_hash'] = int(row[2])
        user['name'] = row[3]
        users.append(user)

chats = []
last_date = None
chunk_size = 200
groups=[]

result = client(GetDialogsRequest(
             offset_date=last_date,
             offset_id=0,
             offset_peer=InputPeerEmpty(),
             limit=chunk_size,
             hash = 0
         ))
chats.extend(result.chats)

for chat in chats:
    try:
        if chat.megagroup== True:
            groups.append(chat)
    except:
        continue

print('Choose a group to add members:')
i=0
for group in groups:
    print(str(i) + '- ' + group.title)
    i+=1

g_index = input("Enter a Number: ")
target_group=groups[int(g_index)]

target_group_entity = InputPeerChannel(target_group.id,target_group.access_hash)

mode = int(input("Enter 1 to add by username or 2 to add by ID: "))

for user in users:
    try:
        print ("Adding {}".format(user['id']))
        if mode == 1:
            if user['username'] == "":
                continue
            user_to_add = client.get_input_entity(user['username'])
        #HERE I NEED TO INSERT THE DELETE METHOD HERE   
        elif mode == 2:
            user_to_add = InputPeerUser(user['id'], user['access_hash'])
        else:
            sys.exit("Invalid Mode Selected. Please Try Again.")
        client(InviteToChannelRequest(target_group_entity,[user_to_add]))
        print("Waiting 5 Seconds...")
        time.sleep(5)
    except PeerFloodError:
        print("Getting Flood Error from telegram. Script is stopping now. Please try again after some time.")
    except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
        print("The user's privacy settings do not allow you to do this. Skipping.")
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("Unexpected Error")
        continue
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Comment: i didnt understtand how to add this into my project , im new to python , if you can help  me please that will be nice thanks @JackMoody

Comment: i trired to add this to my project but its not regognize the command