# `dropdf[df.columnName != 'Value']` Not Working?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Why, when running the subsequent code, on the following table, do `Unknown` values still show in the `EVENT_TIME` column?

**Table**:

```
EVENT ID  EVENT_DATE EVENT_TIME 
85        2014/06/19    Unknown
86        2014/07/09   16.54.00
87        2014/07/10   19.24.00
88        2014/07/13   19.45.00 
89        2014/07/15   16.15.00
91        2015/04/20   16.55.00 
92        2015/06/25   12.48.00
93        2015/07/13    Unknown 
94        2015/07/14   17.30.00 
95        2015/07/16   18.05.00 
96        2015/07/29   17.57.00
```

```
df.dropna(inplace=True) #get rid of blanks

df[df.EVENT_TIME != 'Unknown'] #get rid of "Unknown" values

print(df)
```

**Results:**

```
122     3:00:00 PM
123     4:00:00 PM
124     3:45:00 PM
125     4:45:00 PM
126        Unknown
127     4:55:00 PM
128     2:05:00 PM
129     4:15:00 PM
130    11:04:09 PM
131     9:05:00 PM
132     3:20:00 PM
133    11:20:00 PM
134     2:00:00 PM
135     5:44:24 PM
136        Unknown
137     2:35:00 PM
138     3:30:00 PM
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your step to get rid of `Unknown` values, you need to assign the resulting filtered `DataFrame` to a new variable

```
df = df[df.EVENT_TIME != 'Unknown'] # alternative: df = df.query("EVENT_TIME!='Unknown'")
```

You can also do this with [`df.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop), using `inplace=True` (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52547461/4057186))

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['EVENT_TIME']=='Unknown'].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the solution and the additional insights. You too @Bugbeeb!

Answer (score 1):

As @edesz says, you are creating a copy of the dataframe by slicing, so you must reassign the object. If you are going to keep manipulating this new copy, call .copy() after the slice.