# Drop rows from dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataset

I have a dataset looks like below:

```
   Attribute:Value  Support
0            VDM:1        9
1            VDM:2        2
2            VDM:3        0
3            VDM:4        0
4            VDM:5        1
5            MDM:1        2
6            MDM:2        6
7            MDM:3        0
8            MDM:4        3
9            MDM:5        1
10            OM:1        2
11            OM:2        6
12            OM:3        0
13            OM:4        3
14            OM:5        1
```

Here I want to delete those rows where support is less than or equals to 4 and value of attribute:value pair is 1 or 2 or 3. After removing rows the the dataset will looks like below:

```
   Attribute:Value  Support
0            VDM:1        9
1            VDM:4        0
2            VDM:5        1
3            MDM:2        6
4            MDM:4        3
5            MDM:5        1
6             OM:2        6
7             OM:4        3
8             OM:5        1
```

The value part will contains only 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for remove rows - but conditions is necessary invert - so instead `&` for `AND` is used `|` for OR, for first mask use `~` for invert mask and for second condition is used [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) `>` for invert `<=`:

Also for values after `:` is used [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) or [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
mask = ~df['Attribute:Value'].str.split(':').str[1].isin(['1','2','3']) | df['Support'].gt(4)
```

Because:

> The value part will contains only 1,2,3,4,5.

is possible use:

```
mask = (df['Attribute:Value'].str.extract(':(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).gt(3) | 
        df['Support'].gt(4))
```

---

```
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)

   Attribute:Value  Support
0            VDM:1        9
3            VDM:4        0
4            VDM:5        1
6            MDM:2        6
8            MDM:4        3
9            MDM:5        1
11            OM:2        6
13            OM:4        3
14            OM:5        1
```

Comment: alternative solution is impressive :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this,

```
s=(df['Attribute:Value'].str.split(':').str[-1]).astype(int)
df=df[(df['Support']>4)|(s>3)]
```

O/P:

```
   Attribute:Value  Support
0            VDM:1        9
3            VDM:4        0
4            VDM:5        1
6            MDM:2        6
8            MDM:4        3
9            MDM:5        1
11            OM:2        6
13            OM:4        3
14            OM:5        1
```

explanation:

1. split attribute and value
2. keep rows is value is greater than 3 or Support is greater than 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df[~(df['Attribute:Value'].str.split(':').str[1].isin(['1','2','3'])&df.Support.le(4))]
```

---

```
   Attribute:Value  Support
0            VDM:1        9
3            VDM:4        0
4            VDM:5        1
6            MDM:2        6
8            MDM:4        3
9            MDM:5        1
11            OM:2        6
13            OM:4        3
14            OM:5        1
```