# How to drop a row from a csv using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to clean some csv files from the Consumer Expenditure Survey. I want to drop any row that has a value of 0 for the Total Expenditure Column (TOTEXPCQ). What is the appropriate python code to do this using Pandas? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this

```
df = df[df.TOTEXPCQ!= 0]
```

OR

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['TOTEXPCQ']==0].index, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
        'TOTEXPCQ': [4, 0, 31, 2, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
df
```

[image]

Then do this:

```
df[df['TOTEXPCQ']!=0]
```

[image]