# How to delete multiple rows in pandas dataframe based on one column object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
    Year  Season
    2000  Winter
    2002  Winter
    2002  Summer
    2004  Summer
    2006  Winter
```

and I want to be able to remove all the rows with Winter so it look like this

```
    Year  Season
    2002  Summer
    2004  Summer
```

Comment: This seems like a rather basic task, what part of it is not covered by the many existing resources on Pandas? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
df = df[df['Season']!='Winter']
```

Explanation: 
`df['Season']!='Winter'` returns a boolean mask that you can use to index the original dataframe, thereby dropping all rows where `season` is `winter`.

See here: [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value