# csv file data cleaning process

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r5mR.png) See the attached screenshot. I want to delete all the rows which contain entries from 'Unnamed' column.
i know that the column can be removed by `data.drop(data.columns[27], axis=1, inplace=True)` but it wont delete the entire rows with it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('/home/syed/ML-Notebook/FL-P1/DATASET_FRAUDE.csv',
                 engine='python',
                 encoding=('latin1'),
                 parse_dates=['FECHA_SINIESTRO','FECHA_INI_VIGENCIA','FECHA_FIN_VIGENCIA','FECHA_DENUNCIO'])


#data.drop(data.columns[27], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(data.info())
```

Comment: i guess deleting entire rows with Column 27 will empty the whole dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[df['Unnamed: 27'].astype(str).map(len) >0]
df
```

Drop Column:

```
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete rows macthing a condition you can do:

`df = df.drop(df[df.column_name == 'Unnamed'].index)`

However this question should be helpfull: [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)