# How to filter a dataframe for a given time range?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe that update every week and I want to drop the data older than 6 months

For example:

I have a dataframe from January until now.

Now it's September 14 and I want to drop the old data, in this case from January until March 14.

In the case we are in December, it´ll have from June until December, and so on.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Months are an arbitrary time period, since the length changes
- Use [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) and filter against the current date minus 182 days
- Alternative, use `relativedelta` from the python `dateutil` module, which can do `months`

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta as rd

# This line is just for creating test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end=datetime.today(), freq='1d').to_pydatetime().tolist()})

# filter out the everything greater than 182 days
df_updated = df[df.datetime > datetime.today() - pd.Timedelta(days=182)]

# alternatively, use the relativedelta
df_updated = df[df.datetime > datetime.today() - rd(months=6)]
```

Comment: I tried again and i did not need the first line
Thank you!

Comment: @DanielaBrieva yes, the first line was just to build a test dataframe.