# How to remove certain rows in dataframe using condtion with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
user_id     user_verified
1              False
2              False
3              False
4              True
5              False
6              True
```

How to remove all the 'False'values and keep 'True' values?

Comment: Use: `df = df[df['user_verified'] == True]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df[df['user_verified'] == True]
```

You can check the condition that way. This will keep the row if `True` in column 2.

You can also drop row based on bolean:

```
df.drop(df[df['user_verified'] == False].index, inplace=True)
```

Or even, to keep the `True`:

```
df = df[df.user_verified]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in a dataframe as specified in a similar format below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(zip(range(1,7), [False, False, False, False, True, False, True]), columns=['user_id', 'user_verified'])
```

You can simply use masking since the *user_verified* is boolean:

```
verified = data[data['user_verified']]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it

```
df = df[df['user_verified'] == True]
```

Or you can also use

```
df = df.loc[df['user_verified'] == True]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = df[df['user_verified'] == True]
```

or(without creating copy):

```
df = df.loc[df.user_verified,:]
```