# How to remove rows from a dataframe based on a particular text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

My Data frame has several columns,

| Id | Name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Camp | 25 |
| 2 | Richard | 35 |
| 3 | John Randell | 29 |
| 4 | John Cameron | 26 |
| 5 | John Jacob | 28 |
| 6 | Oliver | 24 |
| 7 | Eugene | 22 |
| 8 | John Camp | 21 |
| 9 | John Clark | 29 |
| 10 | John Rick | 21 |

Intended Output:

| Id | Name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Camp | 25 |
| 2 | Richard | 35 |
| 4 | John Cameron | 26 |
| 6 | Oliver | 24 |
| 7 | Eugene | 27 |
| 8 | John Camp | 25 |
| 10 | John Rick | 21 |

I need to delete those names starting with John who are not (Camp,Cameron,Rick) while keeping the rest of the names.

1. John Camp
2. John Cameron
3. John Rick

I want to remove only those Johns who aren't in the given three names above, while keeping other names.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: You could split names and drop all johns where lastname not in ('Rick', 'Cameron', 'Camp'), Syntax as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) wit htuple of surname chained by `|` for bitwise `OR` with [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and inverted mask by `~` and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
sur = ['Camp', 'Cameron', 'Rick']

df = df[df['Name'].str.endswith(tuple(sur)) | ~df['Name'].str.startswith('John')]
print (df)
   Id          Name  age
0   1     John Camp   25
1   2       Richard   35
3   4  John Cameron   26
5   6        Oliver   24
6   7        Eugene   22
7   8     John Camp   21
9  10     John Rick   21
```