# deleting rows in pandas that wont be deleted

Tags: python, pandas

The code seems to run without issue but when I run .describe the values are still there. What am I doing wrong?
I am trying to delete -999 values in my dataframe for all the columns with :

```
cols=['#objid','u','g','r','i','z','redshift']
for col in cols:
    data_mag_clean=data_mag.drop(data_mag[data_mag[col] < 0].index)
```

as I said the code runs without errors but nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Drop in place: `.drop(data_mag[data_mag[col] < 0].index, inplace=True)`

Comment: kindly post a snapshot of dataframe with the values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it well, you're trying to delete rows from the dataframe which has -999 value. If this is the case then this should work

```
for col in cols:
    data_mag_clean = data_mag[data_mag.col != -999]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!!! it was the for loop and setting data_mag_clean = data_mag
thanks for helping!!!!