# Trying to drop rows from a pandas dataframe that includes specific integers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I am trying to filter out rows (int in a yearmonth format) from a .csv file. For example trying to drop all rows that contain 202301. It seems no matter how I use the drop() method I am getting the error 'not found in axis'.

The dates are under a header called "Activity Period". There are about 500 rows that I have confirmed have this date but I cannot for the life of me get this drop method to work. The datatype for this column is int, even though stack overflow keeps recommending methods for filtering str.

From beginning:

```
data = pd.read_csv("Air_Traffic_Passenger_Statistics.csv")

cln_columns = data.drop(columns = ["Published Airline", "Published Airline IATA Code", "data_as_of", "data_loaded_at"], axis = 'columns')
```

This worked successfully to remove unnecessary columns, then I'm trying to do:

```
cln_rows = cln_columns.drop('202301')

KeyError: "['202301'] not found in axis"
```

These are not indexed rows, there are several hundred rows that contain this number, so how do I filter out the rows that contain that number?

Forgive me as I'm still very new to python and pandas in general.  Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Comment: `cln_rows = cln_columns[cln_columns["Activity Period"] != 202301]`

Comment: @0x00 that was a better dupe, I've promoted it to the top of the dupe list

Comment: @Nick Im so sorry I just don't think I'm understanding.  Thank you for the help either way. I am still getting an error that says "activity period" is not defined now. And I'm having trouble following the first suggested link to the duplicated question.

Comment: You say in your question `The dates are under a header called "Activity Period"`. So that's what I copied into my comment. Pandas is case and whitespace sensitive for column names so you need to be precise with the column name you use. Assuming you get that correct, the code I gave you will remove all rows where the `Activity Period` value is 202301.

Comment: @Nick Got it, I'm understanding now. I think I was just getting lost in all the edits I was making and overlooking that simple thing. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @WestinT no problems - I'm glad you've figured it out.