# Filter rows of pandas dataframe whose values are lower than 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[21, 1],[32, -4],[-4, 14],[3, 17],[-7,NaN]], columns=['a', 'b'])
df
```

I want to be able to remove all rows with negative values in a **list of columns** and conserving rows with NaN.

In my example there is only 2 columns, but I have more in my dataset, so I can't do it one by one.

Comment: This is what you're looking for `df.loc[(df>0).all(axis=1) | df.isnull().any(axis=1)]` ?

Comment: yes exactly what I'm looking for if I change df to df[cols]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to apply it to all columns, do `df[df > 0]` with `dropna()`:

```
>>> df[df > 0].dropna()
    a   b
0  21   1
3   3  17
```

If you know what columns to apply it to, then do for only those cols with `df[df[cols] > 0]`:

```
>>> cols = ['b']
>>> df[cols] = df[df[cols] > 0][cols]
>>> df.dropna()
    a   b
0  21   1
2  -4  14
3   3  17
```

Comment: In my case it's not all columns only a subset

Comment: @dooms I've made one further update, please check the latest revision

Comment: @dooms are you getting an error? or unexpected output? could you detail a bit?

Comment: (I've updated my question) if I use cols=['b'] this will also remove the last row of my dataframe, that's not what I want

Answer (score 15):

I've found you can simplify the answer by just doing this:

```
>>> cols = ['b']
>>> df = df[df[cols] > 0]
```

`dropna()` is not an in-place method, so you have to store the result.

```
>>> df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: This code results in an empty dataframe because column 'a' would be replaced by all NaNs because the filter doesn't include that column. I could modify this answer to include that but then it would be pretty much the same as the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution for this that doesn't change the dtype (which will happen if NaN's are mixed in with ints as suggested in the answers that use `dropna`. Since the questioner already had a NaN in their data, that may not be an issue for them. I went with this solution which preserves the `int64` dtype. Here it is with my sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[0, 1, 2], 'b': [-1,0,1], 'c': [-2, -1, 0]})
columns = ['b', 'c']
filter_ = (df[columns] >= 0).all(axis=1)
df[filter_]


   a  b  c
2  2  1  0
```