# How subtract a Dataframe with totals another Dataframe based on condition and until 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, subtraction

I'm new with python and pandas so here's my question:

I have two dataframes, df1 has two columns one for labels and one for integers which correspond to the Toal of each label while df2 contains the quantity used by day. I would like to subtract each row of df2 until df1 is equal or closer to 0 and add a column to df1 the date of the last row subtracted (it could be in a new dataframe df3). The subtraction needs to have two conditions where:

1. labels need to be equal
2. subtraction can not be minor to 0

df1 = [DF with Totals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBZa4.png)

df2 = [DF with quantities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42A3A.png)

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650833/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum) and it is what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a .cumsum() and .idxmin() will help with this.

1. Join your dataframes on label
2. Create a new "Running Quantity" column that is a .cumsum() on the "Quantity" column ([pandas documenation on .cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html); [blog post on .cumsum()](https://datagy.io/pandas-cumulative-sum/))
3. Create a new "Running Total" column that is "Total" - "Running Quantity"
4. Filter to only the positive values in "Running Total" ([StackOverflow answer about filtering out negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34243246/5618434))
5. Filter to the minimum value of "Running Total" per label using .idxmin() ([pandas documentation on .idxmin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html); [StackOverflow answer about .idxmin()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59343150/5618434))

This should give you a three-column data frame with one row per label, the date when the running total was closest to but not lower than 0, and the amount (Total - Running Quantity at that date).

Comment: But how can I avoid for the cumulative sum to skip from label a to label b. What I mean is that when applying .cumsum() it will sum no matter the label having a total quantity of label b equal to the sum of total a + total b