# How to filter data from csv file based on certain conditions using pandas dataframe

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, pandas

I have below data. These are satellite number ,its state and value.
Here Value of status 'B' is changing either 0 or some value. Value of 
status 'A' is always 0.  Sat with status A and Val=0 for corresponding status 'B'is not acceptable 
and not counted.

My aim is to iterate through each row and find correct Satellite present at each row. If any row is all A or B=0 that row is not counted.

So my desire output is :
 a=3,1,1,1
 Count=4 ,Row 4 is not counted

```
sv-01   sv-02  SV-03  state-01 state-02 state-03    val-01   val-02  val-03
 7        12     8         B          B         B     .23     0.34    1.03
 7        12     8         B          B         A     .35     0       0
 7        12     8         B          A         A     1.45    0       0
 7        12     8         A          A         A      0      0       0
 7        12     8         A          B         B      0      0     3.21
```

# My python implementation is

```
  mask = read_data.filter(like='state').eq('A')
  result_count_Nj1 = mask.sum(axis=1).rsub(3)
```

# I have tried

```
mask = read_data.filter(like='state').eq('A')  and read_data.filter(like='state').eq('B'!=0)
```

# But it shows error. Please suggest where I am making mistake

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by Value, State, and Status; that said, would this framework be helpful?

`df2 = df.drop(df[(df['state-01'] == 'A') & (df['val-02'] == 0)].index)`

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression

Comment: @ Evan.Yeah it would be state. Value is nothing but val-01,val-02,val-03. Then how would I count number of satellite at each row and number of count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
#check B values
maskB = read_data.filter(like='state') == 'B'
print (maskB)
   state-01  state-02  state-03
0      True      True      True
1      True      True     False
2      True     False     False
3     False     False     False
4     False      True      True

#check not 0 values for B values only
mask0 = read_data.filter(like='val').where(maskB.values, 0) != 0
print (mask0)
   val-01  val-02  val-03
0    True    True    True
1    True   False   False
2    True   False   False
3   False   False   False
4   False   False    True

a = mask0.sum(1)
print (a)
0    3
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    1
dtype: int64

b = mask0.any(1).sum()
print (b)
4
```

Comment: @ Jezrael . You are genius man !! Have tried many conditions for hours but not useful

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Comment: @ Jezrael. I was close to maskB but did not apply mask.values :)

Comment: Yes, there is problem need same columns names in both masks or simplier use `values` for numpy array ;)