# Efficiently delete rows in Pandas DataFrame if referenced file does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame, `df`, which has a `path` column which has paths to image files for analysis. Some of the images in this dataset do not actually exist, so I need to selectively remove rows with a nonexistent image `path`.

Currently, I am looping through the entire dataframe and reassigning it like so:

```py
for index, sample in df.iterrows():
    if not os.path.isfile(sample['path']):
        df = df.drop(index)
```

However, as my dataset contains tens of thousands of images, this is extremely slow.

I've also looked at using an approach like in this more general question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression/54489452#54489452):

```py
df = df.drop(df[not os.path.isfile(df['path'])].index)
```

However, this does not work as `os.path.isfile` is incompatible with Pandas DataFrames.

I feel like there must be a better way to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote for a list comprehension instead of `apply()` for performance and use the output as boolean index for slicing:

```
df[[os.path.isfile(i) for i in df['path']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

try using [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on rows (axis=1) to get a boolean index of which rows matched your condition:

```py
df = df.drop(df.apply(lambda row: not os.path.isfile(row['path']), axis=1))
```

Comment: note: using `.apply` with a python function might not have a performance advantage over looping with `iterrows` or a list-comprehension, as it needs to execute a python function on each row (so it leaves the Cython space that makes "native" pandas/numpy functions so fast).