# Remove rows from dataframe if one column matches a value - Python 3.6

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `csv` that looks like this:

```
screen_name,tweet,following,followers,is_retweet,bot
narutouz16,Grad school is lonely.,59,20,0,0
narutouz16,RT @GetMadz: Sound design in this game is 10/10 game freak lied. ,59,20,1,0
narutouz16,@hbthen3rd I know I don't.,59,20,0,0
narutouz16,"@TonyKelly95 I'm still not satisfied in the ending, even though its longer.",59,20,0,0
narutouz16,I'm currently in second place in my leaderboards in duolongo.,59,20,0,0
```

I am able to read this into a `dataframe` using the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

That works great. I get the following dimensions when I `print(df.shape)`
`(1223726, 6)`

I have a list of usernames, like below:

```
bad_names = ['BELOZEROVNIKIT',  'ALTMANBELINDA',    '666STEVEROGERS',   'ALVA_MC_GHEE',     'CALIFRONIAREP',    'BECCYWILL',    'BOGDANOVAO2',  'ADELE_BROCK',  'ANN1EMCCONNELL',   'ARONHOLDEN8',  'BISHOLORINE',  'BLACKTIVISTSUS',   'ANGELITHSS',   'ANWARJAMIL22',     'BREMENBOTE',   'BEN_SAR_GENT',     'ASSUNCAOWALLAS',   'AHMADRADJAB',  'AN_N_GASTON',  'BLACK_ELEVATION',  'BERT_HENLEY',  'BLACKERTHEBERR5',  'ARTHCLAUDIA',  'ALBERTA_HAYNESS',  'ADRIANAMFTTT']
```

What I want to do is loop through the dataframe, and if the `username` is in this list at all, to remove those rows from `df` and add them to a new `df` called `bad_names_df`.

Pseudocode would look like:

```
for each row in df:
    if row.username in bad_names:
        bad_names_df.append(row)
        df.remove(row)
    else:
        continue
```

My attempt:

```
for row, col in df.iterrows():
    if row['username'] in bad_user_names:
        new_df.append(row)
    else:
        continue
```

How is it possible to (efficiently) loop through `df`, with over 1.2M rows, and if the username is in the `bad_names` list, remove that row and add that row to a `bad_names_df`? I have not found any other SO posts that address this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression involving len(string) giving KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression-involving)

Comment: The general operation is the same, which is removing rows based on a boolean condition. There are some good answers there on how to do just that.

Comment: But its _also_ appending rows. And the condition is different. That, by definition, necessitates a different post. I suggest you re-read the definition of a duplicate before flagging a post, which clearly is not a duplicate, as a duplicate.

Comment: Isn't the objective to separate/filter the rows? Is appending necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a mask using `isin`:

```
mask = df["screen_name"].isin(bad_names)
print (df[mask])  #df of bad names
print (df[~mask]) #df of good names
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a lambda then filter as follows:

```
df['keep'] = df['username'].apply(lambda x: False if x in bad_names else True)
df = df[df['keep']==True]
```

Comment: So this creates a new column, `keep`, and fills it with a `True` or `False` value. Then, I recreate that `df` based on if that value is `True`. Is there a more memory efficient way with more than ~1M rows? (It's fine if not :)), additionally, where am I creating the second df with the bad names? `bad_names_df = df[df['keep']==False]`?

Comment: Sure: `df[~df['username'].apply(lambda x: False if x in bad_names else True)]` would work too.