# Python Pandas: Delete all rows of data below first empty cell in column A

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file that gets mailed to me every day and I want to write a script to clean up the data before I push it in a database. At the bottom of the csv file are 2 empty rows *(Row 73 & 74 in image)* and two rows with some junk data in them *(Row 75 & 76 in image)* and I need to delete these rows.

[image]

To identify the first empty row, it might be helpful to know that Column A will always have data in it until the first empty row *(Row 73 in image)*.

Can you help me figure out how to identify these rows and delete the data in them?

Comment: df.dropna() drops rows with NaNs, If you have NaNs in each row to drop, you can use this. This also might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression-involving

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check misisng values by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html), create cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and filter only if equal `0` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Also this solution working if no missing value in first column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['as','bf', np.nan, 'vd', 'ss'],
                   'B':[1,2,3,4,5]})

print (df)
     A  B
0   as  1
1   bf  2
2  NaN  3
3   vd  4
4   ss  5

df = df[df['A'].isna().cumsum() == 0]
print (df)
    A  B
0  as  1
1  bf  2
```