# How to delete rows that contain the same string again and again

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like below

```
  Name                                    Mail-Body
 Oliver                         I am recently doing AAA, BBB and BBB....
  Jack                          Here is my report. It seemed AAA was.. so AAA is..   
 Jacob                          How are you doing? Next week we launch our AAA porject...
```

And with this DataFrame, I would like perform some data analysis. 
But I found out emails containing names such as "AAA" and "BBB"so many times tend to be just a scheduling notification and something like that so it is pretty much meaningless. 
So I would like to drop all the rows that contain the same string such as "AAA" and "BBB"more than 5 times in Mail-Body column.

Is there any pythonic way to drop all rows?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression-involving ?

Answer (score 2):

**Sample**:

```
print (df)
     Name                                        Mail-Body
0  Oliver     I AAA BBB am recently doing AAA, BBB and BBB
1    Jack   AAA AAA. AAA BBB It seemed AAA was.. so AAA is
2   Jacob      AAA AAA BBB BBB AAA BBB AAA AAA BBB BBB BBB
3     Bal                                          AAA BBB
```

If want remove rows with `AAA` more like 5 times it means need filter rows with less like `5` values of `AAA` with [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html), [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df0 = df[df['Mail-Body'].str.count('AAA').lt(5)]
print (df0)
     Name                                     Mail-Body
0  Oliver  I AAA BBB am recently doing AAA, BBB and BBB
3     Bal                                       AAA BBB
```

If want filter like `AAA` or `BBB` values sum together per row, not important how much `AAA` and how much `BBB` use `AAA|BBB` pattern:

```
df1 = df[df['Mail-Body'].str.count('AAA|BBB').lt(5)]
print (df1)
  Name Mail-Body
3  Bal   AAA BBB
```

If want test separately `AAA` and `BBB` - chain masks by `|` for bitwise `OR` - so it means filter less like 5 values of `AAA` or less like `5` values `B`:

```
df2 = df[df['Mail-Body'].str.count('AAA').lt(5) | df['Mail-Body'].str.count('BBB').lt(5)]
print (df2)
     Name                                        Mail-Body
0  Oliver     I AAA BBB am recently doing AAA, BBB and BBB
1    Jack   AAA AAA. AAA BBB It seemed AAA was.. so AAA is
3     Bal                                          AAA BBB
```

And if want filter with and by `&` for bitwise `AND` solution is:

```
df3 = df[df['Mail-Body'].str.count('AAA').lt(5) & df['Mail-Body'].str.count('BBB').lt(5)]
print (df3)
     Name                                     Mail-Body
0  Oliver  I AAA BBB am recently doing AAA, BBB and BBB
3     Bal                                       AAA BBB
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I would like to delete rows containing "the same particular phrase more than 5 times" so it is not necessarily "AAA" only. 
I would like to delete rows containing "BBB" more than five times as well as "CCC" and such.  Is there a way to recognize the same string in python?

Comment: @wannabeAIengineer - Not 100% sure how need filtering, so answer was edited with all solutions, please check it.