# Python z-score replace by mean or some other value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have sensor data in the form of a pandas `DataFrame` along three columns (X,Y,Z). I thought about removing the rows where a row has in any column a z-score higher than 2.5 by doing

```
df = df[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df)) < 2.5).all(axis=1)]
```

But this discards the entire row so also for other columns which may have normal values. What should be the proper way to replace these abnormal high (or low) values by the mean or maybe a value closer to the mean?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression-involving