# Delete rows in a dataframe by a range of dates

Tags: pandas, date, range, drop

[image]I have a dataframe with a column 'date' (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) and datetime64 type.

I want to drop/eliminate rows by selecting ranges of dates. How can I do this on python/pandas?

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering Pandas DataFrames on dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates)

Comment: If your dates are unique, you should make it your index.  However, I think the easiest way would be to use boolean slicing.  `df[~df.date.between(date1, date2)]`

Comment: Hello piRSquared, how do you input date1 and date2, as timestamps?

Answer (score 0):

(I cannot post comments, thus I dare to put an answer) The following questions also refer to deleting or filtering a data frame based on the value of a given column:

[Delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression involving len(string) giving KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression-involving)

[Deleting DataFrame row in Pandas based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172851/deleting-dataframe-row-in-pandas-based-on-column-value)

Basically, you can pass a boolean array to the index operator `[ ]` of the data frame, this returns the filtered data frame. [Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) the pandas v1.0.1 (!) documentation of how to index data frames. Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas#21415990) is helpful.