# How to remove rows that have "false" for every column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I see a lot of questions related to dropping rows that have a certain value in a column, or dropping the entirety of columns, but pretend we have a Pandas Dataframe like the one below.

In this case, how could one write a line to go through the CSV, and drop all rows like 2 and 4? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You apply the `all` operator to the vector of rows.  Perhaps more readable would be `not any(entire row)`

Comment: Also, please note that posting `images` of code, results, etc. is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
~((~df).all(axis=1))
```

to get the rows that you want to keep/drop. To get the dataframe with just those rows, you would use

```
df = df[~((~df).all(axis=1))]
```

A more detailed explanation is here:

[Delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression involving len(string) giving KeyError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression-involving/27360130)

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    value=df.shape[1]
    count=0
    for column_name in column_names:
        if df.loc[[i]].column_name==False:
            count=count+1
    if count==value:
        df.drop(index=i,inplace=True)
```