# How to iterate over list elements when each list is an element in a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, loops

I have this Pandas series that contains lists of countries as following:

```
[United States of America]                                                     17851
[]                                                                              6288
[United Kingdom]                                                                2238
[France]                                                                        1654
[Japan]                                                                         1356
                                                                               ...  
[Canada, Switzerland, France]                                                      1
[Canada, Hungary, United Kingdom]                                                  1
[France, Germany, Italy, Romania, United Kingdom, United States of America]        1
[Germany, Russia, United Kingdom, United States of America]                        1
[Germany, Serbia]                                                                  1
Name: production_countries, Length: 2390, dtype: int64
```

I want to iterate over it and delete any element that has `United States of America` in it.
I tried:

```
for row in df.production_countries:
    if 'United States of America' in row:
        df.drop(row)
```

But it gives me the following keyerror:

```
KeyError: "['United States of America'] not found in axis"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression)

Comment: No, because the iterable element in my case is a list.

Comment: In particular, you must reference the list, not the row as a whole.  Write the condition based on that column.  We can't fix your code, since you failed to post the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This one liner should work : `df = df.drop(df["United States of America" in df.production_countries].index)`