# Remove row based on sum of numpy array within each entry in df column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I feel I'm making this harder than it should be: what I have is a dataframe with some columns whose entries each contain numpy arrays (the names of the columns containing these arrays is in an array called `names_of_cols_that_contain_arrays`). What I want to do is filter out rows for which these numpy arrays have a sum value of zero. [This is a similar question on which my code is based, but it doesn't seem to work with the iterator over rows in each column.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression)

What I have currently in my code is

```
for col_name in names_of_cols_that_contain_arrays:
  for i in range(len(df[col_name])):
    df = df[df[col_name][i].sum() > 0.0]
```

which doesn't seem that efficient but is a first attempt that explictly goes through what I thought would be the correct method. But this appears to return a boolean, i.e.

```
Traceback
...
KeyError: True
```

In fact in most cases to the code above I get some error associated with a boolean being returned. Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: can you provide sample dataframe and your expected output from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

You can try:

```
df=df.loc[df['names_of_cols_that_contain_arrays'].map(sum)>0]
#OR
df=df.loc[df['names_of_cols_that_contain_arrays'].map(np.sum).gt(0)]
```

Sample dataframe used:

```
from numpy import array

d={'names_of_cols_that_contain_arrays': {0: array([-1,  0, -8]),
  1: array([-1, -2,  5])}}

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Ah yes, this has fixed the issue! (just with the `for col_name in names_of_cols_that_contain_arrays` added back in), I didn't realise this `.map` function was a thing until recently, didn't appreciate it until now, think I need to do more investigating of it.