# How to Compare if the Values between 2 Columns have around the Same Number ~ Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df, where I'm trying to compare 2 columns, and if they have around the same value in the same row, I want it to be dropped from the df.
i.e.:

```
   A       B  
1  3.21   3.15
2  6.98   2.07
3  5.41   8.95
4  0.32   0.30
```

I would want only rows 2/3 to remain in the df, because in rows 1/4 A and B are similar to each other.

I've tried to do something like if `i` in column A is within a range (+/- 15% of the value of row B) remove that row, but it didn't work. Didn't know if there was some sort of built in function that pandas had for that.

Comment: looks like you want to conditionally drop rows, is that correct? This previous post may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression

I think it would look something like `df.drop(df[((df.A -df.B)/ df.B) < .15].index)`

Comment: @bartius did not know about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this by passing `rtol` parameter to `numpy.isclose`:

```
result = df[~np.isclose(df.A, df.B, atol=0, rtol=0.15)]
#       A     B
# 2  6.98  2.07
# 3  5.41  8.95
```

Answer (score 2):

You could define your lower and upper bounds on permissable values

```
lower = df["A"]*0.85
upper = df["A"]*1.15
```

and then filter using `pandas.Series.between`

```
df[~df["B"].between(lower, upper)]
```