# Pandas remove row from dataframe dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` dataframe as

```
name    dist
a       10
b       11
c       5
d       3
```

I want to iterate through the dataframe and for each row, I want to check a condition using column `dist` on all other rows, and if it falls below a threshold, I need to delete that row. This threshold itself is computed as a function of the `dist` values of other rows. How can I efficiently use `iterrows()` so as to drop the rows without iterating through all the rows in a nested loop?

Here is how I am currently doing:

```
ind_to_drop=[]
for idx1, row1 in df.iterrows():
    for idx2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        if idx1!=idx2:
            val = myfunc(row1.dist, row2.dist) #This is the function to compute that value
            if val>0:
                ind_to_drop.append(idx2) #here we want to drop the row with index idx2
```

Instead of appending the indices in `ind_to_drop` can we remove the row dynamically so that the number of iterations can be reduced?

Comment: What is the condition? Please be more specific and mention the details that are safe and secure to share.

Comment: Do you mind to produce an [mcve]?

Comment: Please check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression

Comment: @ManjunathKMayya If I drop the row a subsequent iteration will give missing index.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani please see the updates in the question

Comment: For performance you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html.

Comment: So you want to drop a row r, if there exists some other row r2, such that `myfunc(r2.dist, r.dist) > 0`?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame()
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    other_rows_func = df.iloc[[x for x in range(len(df)) if x != i]]['dist'].mean()
    if row['dist']>other_rows_func:
        ndf = ndf.append(row)
```

Here, I check if the dist of the row is lower than the mean of all other rows. You can use your desired function.
Output:

[image]

Comment: I ain't gonna downvote, but how did you know what condition the OP asked for?

Comment: vectorisation would be much more efficient in this solution that `iterrows`

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani I updated the question, for this case you can consider the function to return a value and we need to drop the row when it exceeds a threshold, for eg 0 as shown in the example.

Comment: Can I do this in the same dataframe instead of creating `ndf`?