# delete column based on two conditions in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete column based on two conditions in a dataframe.
I am trying to delete a column from a data frame and I wrote the following code

```
DATAFRAME= DATAFRAME.drop(DATAFRAME.loc[(DATAFRAME['COLUMN1'] ==80) & (DATAFRAME['COLUMN2'] =='86%')])
```

and its showing an error.

"[col1,col2,col3,col4....coln] not found in axis"

selection is working

```
DATAFRAME.loc[(DATAFRAME['COLUMN1'] ==80) & (DATAFRAME['COLUMN2'] =='86%')]
```

Comment: Are you deleting colums in a table or rows?

Comment: rows in dataframe

Comment: Hi, please consider providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
DATAFRAME = DATAFRAME.loc[~((DATAFRAME['COLUMN1'] ==80) & (DATAFRAME['COLUMN2'] =='86%'))]
```

Comment: This is selection and showing wrong invalid syntax

Comment: It was a typo. just fixed it

Comment: i was planning to get rid from all the data where coulmn1==80 and column2=86%, seems like it removed everything where column1==80, whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since selection works as intended you can get the index of the rows meeting your criteria and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27360130/18481969) approach. For your case it would look like this:

```
DATAFRAME.drop(DATAFRAME.loc[(DATAFRAME['COLUMN1'] == 80) & (DATAFRAME['COLUMN2'] == "86%")].index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just filtering here?

```py
import pandas as pd
DATAFRAME = pd.DataFrame(
    {"COLUMN1":[80, 100, 80],
    "COLUMN2": ['84%','85%', '86%' ]})
```

These are the indicies where your conditions are satisfied

```py
cond = (DATAFRAME['COLUMN1'].eq(80) &  
     DATAFRAME['COLUMN2'].eq('86%'))
```

```sh
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

So in order to drop them you can just filter

```py
DATAFRAME[~cond]
```

which gives you the following output

```sh
   COLUMN1 COLUMN2
0       80     84%
1      100     85%
```