# How to drop multiple conditions including NaN using loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, conditional-statements

First of all I am importing a csv file data to pandas

Now I have the following data

| Schooltyp | Name | ParentName | ParentAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Public | Tom | John | Nanostreet |
| Private | Bill | Sally | NaN |
| Public | Ron | Tony | Burystreet |
| Public | Danny | Nate | NaN |
| Private | Stewart | Ben | PringleStreet |

I need to remove data
where Schooltyp = Public and ParentAddress is null.

I tried different solutions. This is the latest solution I have currently used which results in an error due to the particular condition I chose  `(data['ParentAddress'].isnull)`

```
data = pd.read_csv("dataload.csv", sep = ';',  error_bad_lines=False )

indexnames = data[(data['Schooltype']=='Public') & (data['ParentAddress'].isnull)].indexes
data.drop(indexnames, inplace = True)

data.to_csv('finaldata.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

Am I using the right approach, is there a better way in doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression)

Comment: @VladimirFokow it didnt work earlier and suddenly now it works! However your approach works to and I did change the question in regards to the answer but I am not too experienced in Stackoverflow to know whether its a question worth keepin or not! I voted with you since you seem to be more advanced than I am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all rows where `Schooltyp` is "Public" and `ParentAddress` **is null**:

```py
should_be_removed = (df['Schooltyp'] == 'Public') & df['ParentAddress'].isna()

df.loc[~ should_be_removed]
```

**Result:**

```py
  Schooltyp     Name ParentName  ParentAddress
0    Public      Tom       John     Nanostreet
1   Private     Bill      Sally            NaN
2    Public      Ron       Tony     Burystreet
4   Private  Stewart        Ben  PringleStreet
```

> *Notes:*
>
> `.ne()` is equivalent to `!=`, just less typing.
>
> There is also a method `.eq()` which is the same as `==`.
>
> To invert a condition, you can put `~` before it.