# How can I drop rows based on given conditions in pandas and how to force converting data types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I want to drop rows that don't verify a condition, I tried the code below, but it's not working

```
sample.drop(sample.loc[(sample.service == 'ftp') & (sample.is_ftp_login.isna())].index, inplace=False)
```

I also tried a loop, with condition isna() and with ' ', but it didn't work

```
for index, row in sample.iterrows():
    if row['service'] == 'ftp' and row['is_ftp_login'].isna():
        sample.drop([index])
```

I also want to change types from object to int and from float to int, (I tried both lines) it returns cannot convert to Class int.

```
sample['ct_ftp_cmd']=int(sample['ct_ftp_cmd'])
sample['ct_ftp_cmd']=str(int(sample['ct_ftp_cmd']))
```

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this, Thanks.
I

Comment: What is not working? Can you provide minimal reproducible example of the data?

Comment: to change types, you need to set the `dtype` attribute.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression

Comment: @mozway i expect it to drop rows where the condition isn't verified, but when i execute it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I solved the problem.
I was able to convert the string type to numeric using this:

```
sample['ct_ftp_cmd']= pd.to_numeric(sample['ct_ftp_cmd'])
```

and I dropped rows based on a given condition using this:

```
sample = sample.drop(sample[(sample.service == 'ftp') & (sample.is_ftp_login.isna())].index)
```