# Why is my dataframe unable to drop negative values appropriately?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I have a dataset and want to drop rows which contain negative values for a specific column. I have tried three different ways and all yield the same very odd outcome.

I will lay out my interaction with the dataframe, show the dataframe and the 'wrong' result that I am getting vs. what I would like to get.
Lastly I'll show what I tried so far.
Using Python3.

After import `data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')`,

- I interrogate the dataframe for shape, min/max values and a data time span using pandas functionality, but I don't alter it.
- I drop a number of columns using `short data = data.drop(['Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'], axis=1)` and ensure that the remaining columns are floats using`.astype()`
- Finally I sort the dataframe from small to big `sorted_data = short_data.sort_values(['Col2'], axis=0, ascending=[True])`

At this point I want to drop all rows where Col2 has negative values. However all three approaches that I have tried so far have delievered the same 'wrong' result. Instead of dropping negatives, they drop everything except 0.

```
# my input dataframe 'sorted_data'
               Col1        Col 2
249182         0.3         -8.82
132350         0.3         -7.08
56440         -0.2         -4.66
265662         2.8         -1.17
143497        -0.3          0.00
...            ...           ...
35475         98.5        906.23
35526         98.5        906.23
35338         98.6        906.25
35834         98.5        906.28
35793         98.5        906.39

[286996 rows x 2 columns]


# my wrong output dataframe
              Col1          Col2
143497        -0.3           0.0
172367         0.1           0.0
172366         0.2           0.0
172365         0.2           0.0
172364         0.2           0.0
...        ...         ...           ...
201443         0.2           0.0
201460         0.1           0.0
201445         0.2           0.0
201444         0.2           0.0
201446         0.2           0.0

[137023 rows x 2 columns]
```

I got to this odd result via three different ways:

```
# dropping negatives
positive_data = sorted_data.drop(sorted_data.loc[sorted_data["Col2"] < 0.0].index, inplace=False)

#keeping positives
positive_data = sorted_data[sorted_data['Col2'] >= 0.0]

#convert negative to NaN, then drop Nans
sorted_data.loc[sorted_data["Col2"] < 0.0, "Col2"] = 'NaN'
positive_data = sorted_data.dropna(subset = 'Col2')
```

For that third option it replaces the negative values correctly, but when then dropping NaN it gives the same odd result as the other two.

Is my dataframe broken somehow? What could cause this behaviour?

Comment: `positive_data = sorted_data[sorted_data['Col2'] >= 0.0]` should work fine.

Comment: Is the wrong output dataframe in your example sorted? Either on Col1 or Col2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be calling the correct input and output variables for these testings. Why I suggest this:

**Options 1 and 2:** Your lines work perfectly. Using the few rows at hand and your lines exactly ("dropping negatives" and "keeping positives"), I get the 6 zero or positives lines, not "Instead of dropping negatives, they drop everything except 0." So far, I cannot reproduce your issue

**Option 3:** Now that one should cause a problem. "NaN" has nothing to see with an actual *Not a Number*, so `dropna` will not recognize it. You should use [`numpy.nan`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html). A correct syntax for it is

```py
import numpy as np

#convert negative to NaN, then drop Nans
cleared_data = sorted_data.copy()
cleared_data.loc[sorted_data["Col2"] < 0.0, "Col2"] = np.nan
cleared_data.dropna(subset = 'Col2')
```

Then it returns the same, correctly filtered dataframe, on my side.

Hence when you say "it gives the same odd result as the other two", seems indicative that your root problem does not come from either of those 3 attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
Regarding Lines 1 and 2: I have tried all three on a different (random) dataframe and they worked without issues, hence my confusion if my dataframe might somehow be broken. I did double check if all values are indeed floats and they are.
Regarding Line 3: thanks providing the correct syntax! It does work with that approach now. I'll move on with the project and revisit this when I am in a more positive headspace about it... if I find the error I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: @felix_the_cat Nice. Since you've taken the [tour] and the answer allowed you to continue on your project, you should see as adequate to accept this answer and open a new one when the time comes, linking to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
data = {'Col1': {'249182': 0.3,
  '132350': 0.3,
  '56440': -0.2,
  '265662': 2.8,
  '143497': -0.3,
  '35475': 98.5,
  '35526': 98.5,
  '35338': 98.6,
  '35834': 98.5,
  '35793': 98.5},
 'Col2': {'249182': -8.82,
  '132350': -7.08,
  '56440': -4.66,
  '265662': -1.17,
  '143497': 0.0,
  '35475': 906.23,
  '35526': 906.23,
  '35338': 906.25,
  '35834': 906.28,
  '35793': 906.39}}

dff = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

dff.drop(dff[dff['Col2'] < 0].index)
```

Output:

```
        Col1    Col2        
143497  -0.3    0.00
35475   98.5    906.23
35526   98.5    906.23
35338   98.6    906.25
35834   98.5    906.28
35793   98.5    906.39
```

Comment: *"I want to drop all rows where **Col2** has negative values"*

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right you want to drop some rows of your dataFrame using a conditon on the value of some data in the "Column 2", you have 2 options of keeping positive values on the second rows, keeping the positive (1), or dropping the negative (1) :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-100, 100,
                  size=(100, 2)), columns=["Col1", "Col2"])
#%% first solution
keeping_positive_1 = df[df["Col2"] > 0]
df=keeping_positive_1 
#%% or second one
keeping_positive_2 = df.drop(df[df["Col2"] < 0].index)
```

Edit: Sorry i haven't seen the similar one that you tied, are you sure all data are float and not string or something else ?

A similar post is available here :
[How to delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851535/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-conditional-expression)