# Pandas - Delete Rows with only NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, nan

I have a DataFrame containing many NaN values. **I want to delete rows that contain too many NaN values; specifically: 7 or more.**

I tried using the *dropna* function several ways but it seems clear that it greedily deletes columns or rows that contain *any* NaN values.

This question ([Slice Pandas DataFrame by Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881165/slice-pandas-dataframe-by-row)), shows me that if I can just compile a list of the rows that have too many NaN values, I can delete them all with a simple

```
df.drop(rows)
```

I know I can count non-null values using the *count* function which I could them subtract from the total and get the NaN count that way (Is there a direct way to count NaN values in a row?). But even so, I am not sure how to write a loop that goes through a DataFrame row-by-row.

Here's some pseudo-code that I think is on the right track:

```
### LOOP FOR ADDRESSING EACH row:
    m = total - row.count()
    if (m > 7):
        df.drop(row)
```

I am still new to Pandas so I'm very open to other ways of solving this problem; whether they're simpler or more complex.

Comment: There is a `thresh` param to specify the minimum number of non-NA values: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html have you tried this?

Comment: I had not noticed that, thank you. It suits my needs perfectly.

Comment: df.dropna(thresh=3) was all I needed (there are 9 columns in the dataframe)

Comment: I thought I'd put a dynamic method in my answer in the case where you don't the number of columns, glad I could help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically the way to do this is determine the number of cols, set the minimum number of non-nan values and drop the rows that don't meet this criteria:

```
df.dropna(thresh=(len(df) - 7))
```

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: I had to use len(df.columns) instead of len(df).  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Doesn't axis=1 tells it to drop columns? At least in my case columns get deleted when I choose axis=1

Comment: @xkcd it depends on the function, in this case it's the opposite

Comment: `axis=1` will drop the columns, not the rows. "{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}" straight from the docs.

Comment: @PaulEnglish You're correct, I'm not sure if this was due to an error in the docs historically or if I was confusing this with `drop` which does flip the expected meaning of `axis`, will update and thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 5):

The optional thresh argument of **df.dropna** lets you give it the minimum number of non-NA values in order to keep the row.

```
df.dropna(thresh=df.shape[1]-7)
```

Comment: `df.dropna(thresh=2, , inplace=True) # drop extra lines w/o 2 valid values` this was a little more simple and worked perfectly for my application.