# How can i gather data from all sheets in one workbook with Python

Tags: python, excel

i have one workbook with 53 worksheets in excel. I want to get all the data from the sheets, but i need only the data in particular rows and columns. The data structure in workbook is the same in all sheets.

The structure is something like this:

[Excel workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37RCR.png)

Comment: Hi, you should do some level of research. Simply search "python read excel", you would find a lot of questions related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/):

```
import pandas as pd


# Read multiple sheets from one workbook
with pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xlsx') as xlsx:
    df1 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet1')
    df2 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, 'Sheet2')

    # Work with specific columns
    df1[['Column1', 'Column2']] # Do something with these
    df1[['Column1', 'Column2']] # Do something with these
```

Comment: Are these empty rows 1) between rows that contain data or 2) are they at the end of the file? If 1), then you could delete them following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25146613/5535114). If 2), then you should better delete them from within the excel file itself.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir. I change a little bit the code like this:                              df1 = pd.read_excel(xlsx, sheet_name='Page2', skiprows=1, header=None, usecols='F:I') and it works fine. The empty rows look like this:                   
13  HIKVISION   DS-2CE56C0T-IRF  € 18 NaN
17        NaN               NaN   NaN NaN
18  HIKVISION  DS-2CE56C0T-IT3F  € 28 NaN
19        NaN               NaN   NaN NaN

Comment: If this answer was helpful, please consider upvoting :)